# Match string between delimiters, but ignore matches with specific substring

Tags: regex

I have to parse all the text in a paranthesis but not the one that contains "GST"

e.g:

```
(AUSTRALIAN RED CROSS – ATHERTON)
(Total GST for this Invoice $1,104.96)
today for a quote (07) 55394226 − admin.nerang@waste.com.au − this applies to your Nerang services.
```

expected parsed value:

```
AUSTRALIAN RED CROSS – ATHERTON
```

I am trying:

```
^\(((?!GST).)*$
```

But its only matching the value and not grouping correctly.

https://regex101.com/r/HndrUv/1

What would be the correct regex for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work to get the expected string:

```
^\((?!.*GST)(.*)\)$
```

It first checks if it does not contain the regular expression `*GST`. If true, it then captures the entire text.

```
(?!*GST)(.*)
```

All that is then surrounded by `\(` and `\)` to leave it out of the capturing group.

```
\((?!.*GST)(.*)\)
```

Finally you add the BOL and EOL symbols and you get the result.

```
^\((?!.*GST)(.*)\)$
```

The expected value is saved in the first capture group `(.*)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^\((?![^()]*\bGST\b)([^()]*)\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0GHVQ/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?![^()]*\bGST\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are zero or more chars other than `)` and `(` and then `GST` as a whole word (remove `\b`s if you do not need whole word matching)
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `)` and `(`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string

**Bonus**:

If substrings in longer texts need to be matched, too, you need to remove `^` and `$` anchors in the above regex.

Comment: It is also matching `07` which is not desired

Comment: @PyNoob If you mean that the whole string should match then use anchors - https://regex101.com/r/r0GHVQ/1